# I am using a recursive timeout function in Nodejs but it isn't working as expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, settimeout

I have a function that fetches the User count from mongo db :

```
let totalOnlinePlayers = 0;
async function GetTotalOnlinePlayers() {
    totalOnlinePlayers = await db.GetTotalOnlinePlayers();
    setTimeout(GetTotalOnlinePlayers, constants.timeToUpdateOnlineCount);
}
let x = GetTotalOnlinePlayers();
```

in db, the function is as :

```
let GetTotalOnlinePlayers = async function () {
    return User.collection.estimatedDocumentCount();
};
```

and it works as expected.

But I use mongo server running on another vps, and when I restart the mongo server by stopping it for more than 15-20s, the timeout no longer executes.

when I restart my node server, it works fine again
But then again the problem is, I am using socket in my nodeserver and restarting it disconnects player in my game and messes with my gamelogic sometimes.

I can avoid restarting mongoserver, but I am curious on what is causing this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Your `.estimatedDocumentCount()` method probably throws an exception when your db is unavailable.

Try refactoring like this

```js
let totalOnlinePlayers = 0;
async function GetTotalOnlinePlayers() {
  while(true) {
    try {
      totalOnlinePlayers = await User.collection.estimatedDocumentCount();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log ('error in await .estimatedDocumentCount()', e, 'retrying')
    }
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, constants.timeToUpdateOnlineCount)); 
  }
}
```

Then, it's a loop, with simple logic, in your async function to poll the database and wait. This

```
await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, delayInMilliseconds));
```

is the way you spell `await sleep(delayInMilliseconds)` in async javascript. Structuring your code this way makes the flow easier to understand.

Comment: didn't quiet followed this step, but used setInterval instead of setTimeout and it worked fine on restarts too